# Error launching 'Watchkit extension" - SPErrorUnknownMessage

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Trying to run Watchkit - Notification. Receiving the following error:

```
Error launching 'Watchkit extension" - SPErrorUnknownMessage
```

Has anybody else come across this error before or knows what it means? Haven't been able to find anything online about it.

Cheers,
A

Comment: No help to offer, but I am seeing the same in my WatchKit extension that is set to respond to notifications.  Maybe we could consider the similarities in our projects?

Answer (score 11):

I have seen this issue and it was related to an error in the structure of my .apns file - there was a comma missing in the json. Once this was corrected, notifications worked again.

Try looking for errors in the Payload apns file that you are using for this target.

Answer (score 2):

I got this message when I removed the file `PushNotificationPayload.apns` from the WatchKit Extension in Xcode.

Take a look into the *Run*-Section the Schema: If the *Watch Interface* entry shows something like *Dynamic/Static Notification*, it will likely expect some apns-file as notification payload. If that file is missing (or faulty as for Gavin Potts), you'll get that error.

So either fix the apns file, or change the *Watch Interface* entry to *Main* or sth. else.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to PushNotificationPayload.apns. Sometime closing quote may be missing.